# QGIS2Threejs seems to be hung up in building a flat plane

Tags: qgis2threejs

I have installed QGIS 3.12.0 and Qgis2Threejs on a Windows 10 machine.  When I start up Qgis2Threejs exporter I get a message at the bottom of the exporter screen == Building Flat Plane...

The progress bar is about 1/4 complete.

The screen stays this way until I abort QGIS.

After I installed 3.12 I installed 2.x.  Qgis2Threejs appears not to have this problem.

Comment: Hi TimK, welcome to SE-GIS.  Sorry to hear you're having this problem.  I'm going to reply with a comment, since I don't have a definitive answer.  But I do have these thoughts:  I've had good success with Qgis2threejs at QGIS versions 3.8.3 and 3.10.3 (I'm currently running 3.10.3).  Since 3.12.0 is a brand-new release, it may have some bugs affecting Qgis2threejs.  3.12.1 is now out, so you might consider updating and retrying.  Alternatively, you can download previous versions at https://qgis.org/downloads/.

Comment: Hi Stu.  Thanks for the answer.  I think you may be correct.  I did download 2.18.17.  It seemed to have somewhat worked.  It seemed to have gotten to the next step, and it has an older looking screen.  I will try 3.10.3 or 3.10.3.  I assume that they will have the newer looking screen.

Comment: Great, please keep us posted on your progress.

Comment: Hi Stu. I downloaded 3.12.1, thinking that it would solve the problem with an upgrade.  It kind of worked.  The real answer is that Qgis2threejs does not like NULL values in data for the Height parameter, but it accepts NULL values in the Altitude parameter.  When I converted NULL to zero, the problem went away.  I think that is a bug.  I prefer to have NULL handled as zero, or if not available then gracefully backout with an informative error message.

Comment: I just came across the 3D capabilities in QGIS, outside of Qgis2threejs.  Could thus be of value to you?  https://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2018/03/01/working-with-qgis-3d-part-1/